# Auto start Openvpn with one .ovpn file

Tags: openvpn

Hi i bought vpn access form a vpn provider, i got a bunch of .ovpn files.

How can i get openvpn to startup one of these .opvn files under start/boot up?

I would like to, not have to run `openvpn --config VPNservername.ovpn` every time i have to do a reboot.
I'm running ubuntu 12.04 server.

I have installed openvpn

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you have installed `openvpn` from the repo, everything is already prepared for you.

Place the `whatever.conf` file in `/etc/openvpn/` and a daemon will be started for it at boot.

**Edit**

Please note that `*.opvn` will not work, `*.conf` will.

Comment: @staR I don't know if that was really necessary. But anyway, please try to copy `whatever.ovpn` to `/etc/openvpn/`. You'll have to have root rights for this and rename it to `whatever.conf`. Good luck!

Comment: My pleasure :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note, that **/etc/default/openvpn** file contain **AUTOSTART** option. You can add there all your configs without *.conf* at the end you want to autostart. But don't forget to do:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

after editing it.

Comment: This is irrelevant to this question as it was asked a long time ago and the OP is running Ubuntu 12.04. And it dosen't seem the OP is going to accept - he hasn't been on for 3 months.

Comment: Nevertheless, I believe it could help people, who's looking for the answers with similar problems.

Comment: @ubashu I don't think this is irrelevant. Answers should change based on newer versions of software. This is the top result for me when I search.

Comment: This helped me a lot today and should be upvoted, thanks for the answer @AstraSerg

Answer (score 0):

If on ubuntu server: go to rc.local.
vi /etc/rc.local
add the following line
openvpn --config /your/path/file.ovpn
save and reboot.

Comment: wouldn't that block the rest of the /etc/rc.local script from running?

Answer (score 0):

Put the keys, certificates, and client configuration file in the proper folders...

```
/etc/openvpn/ca.crt
/etc/openvpn/client/client0.crt
/etc/openvpn/client/client0.key
/etc/openvpn/client/ta.key
/etc/openvpn/client/client0.conf
```

Enable OpenVPN client service to start at boot and start it...

```
systemctl enable openvpn-client@client0
systemctl start openvpn-client@client0
```

**NOTE:** In the example "client0" is the name of the configuration chosen!

**TIP:** Client configuration example...

```
client
remote <OPENVPN_SERVER_IP_OR_NAME> 1194
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
keepalive 10 120
compress lz4-v2
auth-nocache
remote-cert-tls server

ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client/client0.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client/client0.key
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/client/ta.key 1
```

Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the `ca.crt` into the `/etc/openvpn/client` directory and renamed `.ovpn` to `.conf`. Then it worked.