# Torgaurd will not start with Crontab at reboot

Tags: cron, openvpn

I'm currently using the guide posted on Torguard [here](https://torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=174). Everything work perfectly up until setting up the cronjob to start at reboot.

This is the steps I've taken:

```
crontab -e
```

and then adding this line below my other cronjobs:

```
@reboot sudo openvpn --daemon --cd /etc/openvpn --config TorGuard.Canada.ovpn
```

When I reboot, TorGuard has not restarted.

Comment: sudo doesn't work right in crontabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, sudo doesn't work in crontabs.

Next, you need to specify the full path to the .ovpn file.

Instead of this:

```
TorGuard.Canada.ovpn
```

you need something like this instead:

```
/home/just_some_guy/Downloads/TorGuard.Canada.ovpn
```

However, I believe this is not the recommended way to do this. [See related post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426211/auto-start-openvpn-with-one-ovpn-file)