# How can I automatically connect to wifi + openvpn on startup/resume when "Automatically connect to wifi" is enabled?

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I want to automatically connect to wifi and an openvpn connection on startup and resume. I am able to connect to my wifi network automatically on startup. I am also able to select and connect to my VPN manually after logging in.

I selected *Automatically connect to this VPN when using this connection* for my wifi connection in the Network Connections settings menu (I ran `nm-connection-editor` to open it).

When I start up, I see the icons on the top right of the taskbar repeatedly toggle the Wifi and Openvpn icons, followed by error messages stating that it failed to establish a connection.

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on an HP ENVY x360.

Network device info:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 61
       serial: 7c:b0:c2:f8:8d:29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-46-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.1.126 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:156 memory:df100000-df101fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:b1:a1:76:c3
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual steps depend on how OpenVPN was installed, but if it was installed via the package manager (vs built manually or tarball), there should be a startup script already available. If your (single) config file is in `/etc/openvpn/`, it should be used to start your OpenVPN daemon (background process).

Notes:

1. https://openvpn.net/community-resources/how-to/#configuring-openvpn-to-run-automatically-on-system-startup
2. in the past, I recall the extension had to be `.conf` on linux, and `.opvn` on windows? (going off memory, I've used several OS's w/ OpenVPN)
3. add only a *single* config file to that directory, because by default (it's configurable), openvpn is going to start all config files located there: see `/etc/default/openvpn` & `/etc/init.d/openvpn`
4. This also assumes the authentication info is supplied in the ovpn config file.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/464264/starting-openvpn-client-automatically-at-boot and https://askubuntu.com/questions/426211/auto-start-openvpn-with-one-ovpn-file/426217

Comment: Thank you @michael ! Setting the extension of the `.ovpn` file to `.conf` did the trick!